# Why does my button still have underlined text?

Tags: html, css, button

I'm Creating a button that links to Youtube, and the text inside the button doesn't respond to css code

I tried this html code:

```
<button class = "button"><a href = https://www.youtube.com>This is a button to youtube</a></button>
```

and this css:

```
.button {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:12px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: black;
  font-size:15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color:red;
  border-left: solid transparent;
  border-right: solid transparent;
  border-top: solid transparent;
  border-bottom: solid transparent;
  
  position:relative;
  top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you dont need to use the button tag if you use a tag

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com" class="button">This is a button to youtube</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

When applying your text styles, you have to select your `a` element, not your `button` element:

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  border-left: solid transparent;
  border-right: solid transparent;
  border-top: solid transparent;
  border-bottom: solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

.button > a {
  font-family: arial;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="button"><a href = https://www.youtube.com>This is a button to youtube</a></button>
```

Answer (score -5):

Use a tag, the browser has some default behavior. If you don't like, you can use JavaScript to navigator to youtube

```
<button class = "button" onclick="window.open('https://www.youtube.com', '_blank')">This is a button to youtube</button>
```

Comment: Default styles can easily be changed. There is no need for JavaScript.

Comment: Why use a button with JavaScript when you can easily use an anchor tag?